# uninitialized constant Admin::AdminController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting an "uninitialized constant" error. I am trying to make a "AdminCotroller"(subcontroller) to the ApplicationController to control one area of the website (the "admin" area).

The routing seems to be correctly set up. I attach 2 things (both from: app/controller/admin/ folder) which produce the error:

1) the "parent" controller

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
    layout "admin/layout"
end
```

2) the "child" controller

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::AdminController
```

PS: I wanted to make a separate layout and this was the only solution I could think off.

PPS: [Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tkCh.png)

Comment: try `class Admin::ProductsController < AdminController`. Assuming your admin controller is in a file named `admin_controller.rb`

Comment: error: uninitialized constant AdminController

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check the above file structure, that's what I have used.

And controllers as below:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
  ...
end

class Admin::AdminUsersController < Admin::BaseController
  ...
end
```

Comment: But what is wrong with my question? Your answer implies only a name change of my controlller (Admin::AdminController => Admin::BaseController)

Is it naming problem? Why does this exist?

Comment: Hi @Julian, I have tested yours, it works. Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I messed up those days. I haven't tried a given answer but instead I found a workable solution for naming I would like to share:

```
module Admin
  class UsersController < BaseController
...
  end
end
```

this way you achieve a namespace in a folder "admin" too.